# Find the Parent Attributes of a div class in Python BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

```
    soup = BeautifulSoup(code below, "html.parser")

    <item class="info" data="findthisinfo" example="exa1">

    <div class="exampleclass">
    EXAMPLE INFO
    </div>


    <item class="info" data="findthisinfo1" example="exa0">

    <div class="exampleclass">
    EXAMPLE INFO 2
    </div>

    <item class="info" data="findthisinfo2" example="exa2">

    <div class="exampleclass">
    SOME TEXT
    </div>

    for example in soup.find_all('item', attrs={'class': 'info'}):
        examp2 = example.find_all('div', attrs={'class': 'exampleclass'})
        examp3 = soup('div', text=re.compile("EXAMPLE"))
```

This gives me output of:

```
[EXAMPLE]
[EXAMPLE]
[]
```

I would now like to find the parent class for the two particular output, so for example I need the parent values of `data="findthisinfo"` and `data="findthisinfo1"`

How would I go about in doing this?

Comment: in the example you have given.   data="findthisinfo" and data="findthisinfo1"are the parent classes?? what info do you want?

Comment: i need the values of data= so in this case 'findthisinfo' and 'findthisinfo1' @johnashu

Comment: and why are people minusing my post

Comment: Have you tried anything? That's usually the first step in doing anything. You're getting downvotes because your "question" is just "write some code for me."

Comment: @HenryKeiter Yes I have, I am able to get the parent code but I cant specifically get the 'findthisinfo' because it puts the output into a list [ ]

Comment: I didnt point in the post that I did try many hours to figure out, but gave up and posted here

Answer (score 1):

What you need to do is collect all the `item` tags.

Then iterate over them looking for the `data` attribute

```
items = soup.findAll('item')

for i in items:
    if 'EXAMPLE' in i.text:
        print(i.attrs['data'])
```

prints

```
findthisinfo
findthisinfo1
```

Comment: but i only want the output for the first two, so for EXAMPLE INFO and EXAMPLE INFO2